$f \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}), ||f_h - f||_{\infty} \rightarrow 0 \implies f = g$, uniformly continuous, a.e.
The following question has been asked before, and I'm reasking to get feedback on my attempt.
Question: Suppose $f \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, $f_{h}(x) = f(x+h)$, and
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}||f_{h} - f||_{\infty} = 0
$$
Prove that there exists a uniformly continuous function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f = g$ a.e
Attempt: Let us first think about the case where $f$ is bounded everywhere and $f_h \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. Then, we have that $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f(x+h)-f(h)| \rightarrow 0$, which is the definition of $f$ being uniformly continuous, so $g := f$ works. (Note here that we don't use the bounded everywhere assumption)
Now, to address the general case, I hope to construct a set $A$ such that $m(A) = 0$, and $f_h \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $A^c$. Then, by the above simple case, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A^c$, and we are done.
By assumption that $||f_h - f||_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$, i.e., $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \inf \{M: m(|f_n - f| > M) < \epsilon \} \rightarrow 0$, we have that $\forall \epsilon, \eta > 0, \exists \delta > 0$, s.t. $|h|< \delta_k \implies m(|f_h - f| > \eta) < \epsilon .$ Choosing $\epsilon_k := 2^{-k}, \eta_k := \frac{1}{k}$ and satisfactory $\delta_k$ such that $|h| \leq \delta_k \implies  m(|f_h - f| > \eta_k) < \epsilon_k $, and letting $A_k := \{|f_{\delta_k}- f| > \eta_k \}$, we have that $m(\limsup A_k) = 0$ by Borel-Cantelli (I).
Hence, if $A := \limsup A_k$, then $x \in A^c \implies x \in A_k \text{ almost always} \implies x \in A_n$ whenever $n \geq N(x) \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e., $ |f_{\delta_n}(x)- f(x)| \leq \eta_n $.
Question

I'm not sure how to extend the above to show that $|f_h(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for $h$ sufficently small (i.e., $f_h \rightarrow f$ pointwise on A^c).

I'm also not sure how to extend the above to get that $f_h \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $A^c$.

Lastly, even if the above works, is it true that (via the simple case) we have $f$ uniformly continuous on $A^c$, and we are done? If so, where did we use the fact that $f \in L^{\infty}$?



Hints: $\lim \sup_n f_{1/n}$ is (finite and) uniformly continuous on dense set, so it extends to a uniformly continuous  function $g$ on $\mathbb R$.

I haven't been able to show that $f_{\frac{1}{n}}$ converges uniformly to its limit though: any suggestions on that @geetha290krm?
